# Is there any keyboard mouse macro recorder to save time time on any repeted task?

Tags: windows-xp, portable, productivity

Is there any keyboard mouse macro recorder to save time time on any repeated task?

Answer (score 4):

The Rolls-Royce of macro automation is definitely [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/), well known and used a lot on SuperUser. But you have to type the script by hand. I'm sure others will post less-featured but more easy to use macro recorders.

Comment: It's a pity I can't +1 this *more*, but once will have to do :)

Comment: i'm asking a tool like this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863 for windows

Comment: What can that do that AHK can't?

Comment: AutoHotkey is a little user un-friendly. But I think the recording tool that works with AutoHotkey is called "AutoScriptWriter" and it comes with AHK

Comment: I +1-ed it for you Phoshi ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can use AutoHotkey, but you don't have to write a single line of code yourself. The installation comes with AutoScriptWriter II which can record your actions and make a script for you, which you can customize if necessary:

[image]

AHK really is the bread and butter of automation, and as already mentioned, anything else will have less features. But if you are looking for something simple, the good old popular [Ghost Mouse](http://www.ghost-mouse.com/) is free and very simple to use:

[image]

So small and simple in fact, that it's title doesn't even seem to fit in the window!

AutoHotkey's little cousin, [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) (which AHK is based off), may also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need doing, [Blaze](http://blaze-wins.sourceforge.net/index.php) might be useful.

> Blaze always know what you are doing. Therefore, it uses this information to make your life easier. For instance, adding new commands, new websites or even new quick texts is as easy as it could ever be. Blaze just knows what files or text you have selected or what web page you are currently browsing.
>
> It always know what you are doing.
>   Therefore, it uses this information to
>   make your life easier. For instance,
>   adding new commands, new websites or
>   even new quick texts is as easy as it
>   could ever be. Blaze just knows what
>   files or text you have selected or
>   what web page you are currently
>   browsing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

New: [sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/)

> is an open source scripting app that uses a combination of very simple commands like click, type, and wait, and screenshots to tell Sikuli what to manipulate.

Haven't used it yet, but seems intriguing.