# Is there any task based/action based macro recorder to perform task automated in web browser?

Tags: windows-xp, portable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any keyboard mouse macro recorder to save time time on any repeted task?](https://superuser.com/questions/98880/is-there-any-keyboard-mouse-macro-recorder-to-save-time-time-on-any-repeted-task)

@John T [Is there any keyboard mouse macro recorder to save time time on any repeted task?](https://superuser.com/questions/98880/is-there-any-keyboard-mouse-macro-recorder-to-save-time-time-on-any-repeted-task/99557#99557) suggested this but ,I tested this but it's not sensitive to screen changes. I wanted to use on a web application but some time pages load quickly and sometime slow , so it doesn't work properly. it records action time based but i need task/action based.

I need portable,freeware, Windows XP 32 bit tool.

Comment: Fix up your original question with this information instead of posting a half-done dupe.

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin for Firefox called [**Chickenfoot**](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/). Should be able to do what you want but it is bound to Firefox.